# Unity - Change all objects with a certain tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity and have added a collision script which runs when my player hits a block. If possible I would like it to select every gameObject with a certain tag and disable a specific feature. For example my end product would be to disable the useGravity feature in the attachedRigidbody of every gameObject with the tag "Obstacle" however I'm not sure how I would code it in unity. I have made my current code disable the hit entities gravity but would like to do it for all of them at the same time.

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
    {
        collisionInfo.collider.attachedRigidbody.useGravity = false;
        GameManager.restartDelay = 4f;
        movement.enabled = false;
        FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
    }
}
```

Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On collision, find every gameobject with your tag and put it in an array, then just loop through each object in the array and manipulate it as you please.

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
    {
        GameObject[] obstacles = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Obstacle");
        foreach(GameObject obst in obstacles)
            obst.GetComponent<RigidBody>().useGravity = false;

        GameManager.restartDelay = 4f;
        movement.enabled = false;
        FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all game objects with a certain tag, use [`FindGameObjectsWithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html). It returns an array of gameobjects with the aforementioned tag. Then, it's as simple as looping through the array and changing what you need to on each object.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple...

You are supposed to use [FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) , remember the `s` as there are multiple objects.

And after that, use a `foreach` loop for every item, and then disable the `useGravity`.

Code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.CompareTag(Obstacle))
    {
        GameObject[] allObstacles = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Obstacle");
        foreach(GameObject obstacles in allObstacles)
            obstacles.GetComponent<RigidBody>().useGravity = false;

        GameManager.restartDelay = 4f;
        movement.enabled = false;
        FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
    }
}
```

I hope you're clear with it. <3